# What are the best practices for Nationalized SEO?

Tags: seo, ranking, local-seo

I am working on Internet marketing for one of the Website designing & development company in India which is located in Mumbai. So the website is performing quite well in local search places or up to state level in SERPs. But not with all major locations in my country, so my question is what are the best ways I have to stay on top of the SERPs.

Comment: What is a SERP? A kind of web-service or search engine?

Comment: SERP means "Search engine results pages" I want to say. So can suggest the right solution?

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution (I highly doubt). A search engine like does differentiate it's results by many parameters. For example, when searching for the same search query, two people will almost never see the same search results, as they personalized. The same accounts for regions and other things, that could be used as filter.

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh, if you are looking to outrank others in SERPs in Google, then you will need to have physical presences in other metros. Add those addresses to your Google Local (they will even send you a card via snail mail to that address for address verification).

Once you have verified your address for all the major metros, you need to start pushing your fans for reviews across all these locations.

You might even wan't to get listed in the location specific services (although I cannot really vouch for any other service except Just Dial).

Comment: Thanks for you effort Prasad, but these not the whole picture behind. Yes physical location is one of the ranking factor which can help you to boost your website rank in that particular region, but it's even more bigger. Like if you search for "Online shopping" from you place you will get homeshoop18.com on the top and even if you tried with other locations it stays constant. so that dos't mean it's having physical location at all around. What you think?

Comment: hmm, I see what you mean. So you do not want to get higher rankings for particular locations, but instead want to get a high ranking across all locations (independent of the location). 

Did you try looking at the linking of homeshop18.com (more than 2500+ sites linking to the site).